# apache mina filters

Tags: java, memory-leaks, apache-mina

Is it allowed to call apache mina filters from custom threads? I have timer which periodically calls `NextFilter.messageReceived(...)`. I currently got out of memory exception and wondering could these calls be cause of memory leak?

I am using apache mina 1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that memory leak was caused by profiler intrusion and not by mina finter calls.